# How set own style of stylus in drawing on canvas?

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I'm searching how to set own bitmap like stylus of my path which I draw on canvas. This is exactly implemented in Sketchbook and it is perfect. Which classes I must use? Can you recommend me some solution, please?